# Bug - can't have resizable frame and a label icon

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

Does anyone know how to fix this? if line `A` AND line `B` are included at the same time, then things stop being displayed, but if exclusively one is included, or both are not, then everything works fine. I’m terribly confused. Here’s some reproducible code.

```java
package ui;

import java.awt.*;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(1600, 900);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setBackground(new Color(0xFAFAFA));
        frame.setTitle("App !");
        frame.setResizable(false); // <------ LINE A
        frame.setVisible(true);

        JLabel label = new JLabel();
        label.setText("Hello world!");
        label.setIcon(new ImageIcon("assets/logo-50x50.png")); // <----- LINE B
        label.setBackground(Color.red);
        label.setBounds(0, 0, 250, 250);

        frame.add(label);
    }
}
```

Comment: `frame.setLayout(null);` <-- Bad idea, which is probably why you're trying to make the frame non-resizable.  As a user, I'll be very grumpy (really hate non-resizable windows)

Comment: @MadProgrammer This is not production stuff, just learning and trying out the framework. But thanks for the tip, I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: “Learning” and “production” code should be the same goal 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't make the `frame` visible **before** adding `label`.

```
// NOT HERE
// frame.setResizable(false);
// frame.setVisible(true);

JLabel label = new JLabel();
label.setText("Hello world!");
label.setIcon(new ImageIcon("assets/logo-50x50.png"));
label.setBackground(Color.red);
label.setBounds(0, 0, 250, 250);
frame.add(label);
// HERE
frame.setResizable(false);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked, and so did using `frame.repaint()` at the very end regardless of order.